# Pygame error: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT(): 
            running = False
```

When executing this code, I get the following error:

```
'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: maybe try to look at the error, especially what column said error is on

Answer (score 1):

`pygame.QUIT` is an `int` and not a function. Try removing the parentheses:

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    running = False
```